# How to save pfx file using .net core c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, pem, pfx

I have created code of installing pfx certificate using pem & private key. pfx certificate installed successfully. But i need to save that pfx certificate in specified location(Local folder). My code is given below,

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                  .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                  .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            var pfxConfig = new AppSettings();
            configuration.GetSection(Constants.AppSettings).Bind(pfxConfig);

            string pemFilePath = pfxConfig.PemFilePath;
            string privateKeyPath = pfxConfig.PrivateKeyPath;
            string pfxSavePath = pfxConfig.PfxSavePath;
            string pfxPassword = pfxConfig.PfxPassword;

            byte[] publicPemBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pemFilePath);
            using var publicX509 = new X509Certificate2(publicPemBytes);
            var privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText(privateKeyPath);
            var privateKeyBlocks = privateKeyText.Split("-", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyBlocks[1]);
            using RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
            if (privateKeyBlocks[0] == Constants.BeginPrivateKey)
            {
                rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);
            }
            else if (privateKeyBlocks[0] == Constants.BeginRsaPrivateKey)
            {
                rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);
            }

            var keyPair = publicX509.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
            X509Certificate2 pfxCertificate = new X509Certificate2(keyPair.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));

            //pfxCertificate.Export(pfxSavePath, pfxPassword);

            //Installation of pfx certificate.
            X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(pfxCertificate);
            X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            x509Store.Add(x509Certificate2);
            x509Store.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(Constants.PfxInstallationSuccessMessage);

        }
```

App setting json file is given below,

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "PemFilePath": "F:\\Certificate\\123certificate.pem.crt",
    "PrivateKeyPath": "F:\\Certificate\\123private.pem.key",
    "PfxSavePath": "F:\\Certificate\\sample.pfx",
    "PfxPassword": "password123"
  }
}
```

How to save pfx certificate in a specified location(local system) using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exports returns a byte array that represent your certificate

write that to a file:

```
byte[] certData = pfxCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "MyPassword");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\MyCert.pfx", certData);
```

Comment: pfxCertificate in your case..
the X509Certificate2 Object